# Pattern matching with identical wildcards

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm working with PostgreSQL and want to know whether you can have a wildcard retain its value.

So for example say I had

```
select * from tableOne where field like ‘_DEF_’;
```

Is there a way to get the first and last wildcard to be the exact same  character?

So an example matching result could be: ADEFA or ZDEFZ.

Comment: The relevant section of the manual is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a back-reference:

```
select * 
from some_table
where some_column ~* '^(.)DEF(\1)$'
```

`^(.)DEF(\1)$` means: some character at the beginning followed `DEF` followed by the first character must occur at the end of the string.

The `()` defines a group and the `\1` references the first group (which is the first character in the input sequence in this example)

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4c4d/1

Comment: Maybe use `~` instead of `~*` to match the case sensitive `LIKE` in the question.

Comment: The second pair of parentheses might be removed. We don't want to re-capture that.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression:

```
with test as (
    select 'xABa' as foo
    union select 'xABx'
    union select 'xJBx'
)
select * from test
where foo ~* E'^(.)AB\\1$'
```

Outputs:

```
 foo  
------
 xABx
(1 row)
```

Comment: While the answer is good, it's the same as what a_horse already posted 5 minutes earlier. It doesn't add anything, and should be deleted.