# SQL or regular expression to match strings whose end is like the beginning, but in reverse

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have the query `select * from tbl where column like '%DEF%'`.

Would it be possible to use regular expression to have the characters before `DEF` be the same as those in the end but in reverse?

An example matching result `ASDEFSA`or `TERDEFRET`?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that this was asked about an hour after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033022/postgres-wildcards ? (Not a duplicate, just weirdly similar).

Comment: haha, I saw that question and wanted to know how you would do the same with multiple characters but couldn’t comment on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `reverse` and `replace`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  col LIKE '%DEF%' AND
       REPLACE(col, 'DEF', '') = REVERSE(REPLACE(col, 'DEF', ''))
```

Comment: Ooh, that's ingenious! Remove the invariant part, and see if you're left with a palindrome.